# Why is there no visual feedback when I click an icon in the launcher?

Tags: unity, usability

Whenever I click on the icons in the Unity launcher, no visual feedback is shown. The application just opens.

Without the visual feedback, I won't be able to know whether the click event was registered properly. I end up clicking multiple times, which causes same application to open multiple instances which is a bit irritating.

Those of you who have used a Mac will know that clicking the icons in the dock causes the icons to jump which affirms that the click event was registered properly on the icon.

Is this a bug or is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the icon will "wiggle" while it is launching (like on the Mac) and then you will get little arrowheads next to the icon to show the app is running.  If you're not getting that, please file a bug with

```
ubuntu-bug unity
```

(or `unity-2d-launcher`) if you're using the 2d version.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, still happens for me so I assume it is deliberate (or they have been too lazy to implement it). Pretty poor if you ask me!

Answer (score 0):

you can check the default action upon "click" if you have installed

compizconfig-settings-mananger

start it , click on  Ubuntu unity plugin, go to the experimental tab, check/set what(if any ) launch animation has been set.

But to be honest the "feedback" is not on par with OSX, where the click itself results in direct feedback. Here you only get feedback that the application is starting

there is a bug on it though and a commit with a fix, so we should see an even better unity soon!

[BUG - Unity should provide instant visual feedback](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/893140)